# I am gettign an issues in weather API, getLiveInfo() in HMS Weather Awareness always returning null value

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

In HMS Awareness api basically I am trying to call getLiveInfo() which is used to obtains living index of current day and the next one to two days.

Here i am getting null.
I have completed all the integration steps and added json as well.
Is there anything which is missing at applications end ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getLiveIfo() is currently available in China only. Hope your not in China that is why it is giving null vale.